# How to do a Realm migration in Android?

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realms as a database in Android app. Works fine, but I've added a new label in my user model and I'm getting the error that I need to migrate my schema:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.apelucy.apelucy.app.base.MyApplication: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
                                                   - Property 'User.testRealm' has been added.
```

How can I do the migration? I've found other solutions here but I can't implement them in my code. I can't use a solution of delete and install the app. I now that work in development, but I need to update the app in production.

My UserRespository class:

```
public class UserRepository {

    private static UserRepository sInstance = null;
    private Context mContext = null;



    public static UserRepository getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new UserRepository();
            sInstance.mContext = context;
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    // DATABASE Methods

    public void storeUser(final User user) {
        AppSingleton.getInstance().setUser(user);

        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.insertOrUpdate(user));
        } finally {
            if (realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public User retrieveUser() {
        Realm realm = null;
        User user = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            User userRealmResult = realm.where(User.class)
                    .findFirst();

            if (userRealmResult != null) {
                user = realm.copyFromRealm(userRealmResult);
            }

        } finally {
            if (realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }

        return user;
    }

    public void clearUser() {
        // Clear Database objects
        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.delete(User.class));
        } finally {
            if (realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Init realm in my Application:

```
Realm.init(this);
```

My model change:

```
@SerializedName("test")
@Expose
private String testRealm;
```

Comment: There is a document for migration https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations, also it have a sample app. Have you try it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with this documentation, but I can't do it work

Comment: I think you should post the code that you already do for migration and the error you got. Then we can help you easier. I'm quite sure that follow the docs and sample can help you apply migration because I used to do it

Comment: Actually, I've added the answer of Eirini and yep, is working without crash the app. But, I want keep the data, if is possible, too

Comment: Yes it possible https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java. Also I think always `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` is not good for production app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Migrations allow you to modify the schema of the application, which means that it lets you add, remove, rename tables/fields in the Realm schema. If you change a RealmModel class, then you must write the migration that will map the existing Realm file to reflect the new model classes.

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                                 .schemaVersion(1)
                                 .migration(new MyMigration()) 
                                 .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

The default schema version is 0.

---

Migrations are fairly straightforward:

- you must increment the schema version, so Realm knows you want to increment the schema's version to a specific number
- you must supply a migration that will handle the change from one version to another

Migrations describe the operations to do when you need to go from one schema version to another:

```
public class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        // Migrate from version 0 to version 1
        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            RealmObjectSchema userSchema = schema.get("User");

            userSchema.addField("testRealm", String.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }

        if (oldVersion == 1) { // ...
            // ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return MyMigration.class.hashCode(); }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) { return object != null && object instanceof MyMigration; }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include the Migration class into the config builder

Comment: You're right, that is a good idea for the answer to be complete

Answer (score -3):

Add this in your Application file. This will Realm to delete everything if you add a new table to a column.

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("dbname.realm")
                                     .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                                     .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Comment: Yeah, but... is any solution to do the migration without to have to delete all the data?

Comment: deleting all the data to be able to start fresh is not considered a migration

Comment: He specifically said that he doesn't want to delete all data.